# Yii 4 depedent dropdownlist with preselected values passed from the controller

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

have 4 dropdownlist which are working like charm except when i have preselect values passed from the controller like this

```
public function actionBodyTrim(){
    $trim = new CarTrim;
    $spares = new Spares;

    $spares->makeid  = $_REQUEST['mid'];
    $spares->modelid = $_REQUEST['moid'];
    $spares->bodyid  = $_REQUEST['bid'];
    $spares->trimid  = $_REQUEST['tid'];

    $this->render('bodytrim', array(
                  'trim'=>$trim,
                  'spares'=>$spares
                  )
    );
}
```

When the page is rendered the first dropdownlist is displaying the preselected value. i have tested the second dropdownlist with the code below but it does not fire the Ajax Calls. The result is shown below

```
<div class="span5 leftpull">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="width125"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'makeid'); ?></div>
     <div class="widthtxt"><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'makeid', CHtml::listData(Makes::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'makename ASC')), 'makeid', 'makename'),
                                     array('prompt'=>'Select Makes',
                                           'ajax'=>array('url'=>CController::createUrl('CarModels'),
                                            'beforeSend' => 'function(){$("#carmodels").addClass("loading");}',
                                            'complete' => 'function(){$("#carmodels").removeClass("loading");}',
                                           'type' =>'POST',
                                           'update'=>'#'. CHtml::activeId($model, 'modelid'),
                                           array('class'=>'ajaxlink'),

                                        ))); ?>


                <?php echo $form->error($model,'makeid'); ?>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="carmodels">
     <div class="width125"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'modelid'); ?></div>
     <div class="widthtxt"><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'modelid', empty($model->modelid) ? array('prompt' => 'Select the country first') :
                                      array('ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                                          'url'=>CController::createUrl('BodyType'),
                                                          'update'=>'#'. CHtml::activeId($model, 'bodyid'),
                                                          'prompt'=>'Models',
                                                          array('class'=>'ajaxlink'),

                                               ))); 
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'modelid'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

HMTL code of the Ajax not firing as required.

```
 <div class="row" id="carmodels">
         <div class="width125"><label for="Spares_modelid" class="required">Model <span class="required">*</span></label></div>
         <div class="widthtxt"><select name="Spares[modelid]" id="Spares_modelid">
<optgroup label="ajax">
<option value="type">POST</option>
<option value="url">/spareparts/index.php?r=spares/parts/BodyType</option>
<option value="update">#Spares_bodyid</option>
<option value="prompt">Models</option>
<optgroup label="0">
<option value="class">ajaxlink</option>
</optgroup>
</optgroup>
</select>                   </div>
    </div>
```

Where i am getting it wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed to make it work with a dirty work-round using (if statements ). I just hope there is someone out there with a cleaner code than this.

```
 <?php
             if (isset($model->makeid) && !isset($model->modelid)  ) 
             {              
                            $list = CHtml::listData(CarModels::model()->findAll('makeid=:mid',
                                                                                                                array(':mid'=>$model->makeid)), 'modelid', 'model');
                            echo $form->dropDownList($model,'modelid', $list, 
                                                                          array( 'prompt'=>'Select Models',
                                                                                             'ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST',
                                                                                                                      'url'=>CController::createUrl('BodyType'),
                                                                                                                      'update'=>'#'. CHtml::activeId($model, 'bodyid'),

                                             ))); 

             }

             else (isset($model->makeid) && isset($model->modelid) ){
                      $list = CHtml::listData(CarModels::model()->findAll('makeid=:mid  AND  modelid=:mod',
                                                                                                                array(':mid'=>$model->makeid, ':mod'=>$model->modelid )), 'modelid', 'model');

                    echo $form->dropDownList($model,'modelid', $list, array('prompt'=>'Select Models'));

              }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have mixed up some of the parameters inside your `bodyid` form field. If you look at the generated HTML your ajax request is rendered improperly.

```
<optgroup label="ajax">
<option value="type">POST</option>
<option value="url">/spareparts/index.php?r=spares/parts/BodyType</option>
<option value="update">#Spares_bodyid</option>
<option value="prompt">Models</option>
<optgroup label="0">
<option value="class">ajaxlink</option>
</optgroup>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: Hi Travis could you be more specific and detailed. I have several dropDown Lists and that is why i have the #Spares_bodyid up there which will render the bodystyles when model has changed or selected.